# Concatenate sheet name with values in cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that removes unnecessary columns and copies/ pastes data from one column next to another. I then want it to take the worksheet name (which is variable) and concatenate it with the values in a static range of cells, but only after the columns have been modified.

The macro runs without error until the concatenate step.

Is there a better way to write this or what am I doing incorrectly? The error is "Object variable or With block not set". The error occurs at "Set rngTemp = ws.Range("A21", "H21")" line.

Thank you in advance for your consideration.

```
Sheets("Channel-0").Select
    Range("F21:F62").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("G21:H62").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("H21:L62").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Range("G11").Activate
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("E21:E62").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-39
    Range("G21").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("G19").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngCell, rngTemp As Range
    Set rngTemp = ws.Range("A21", "H21")
    
    For Each cell In rngTemp
        cell.Value = ActiveSheet.Name & cell.Value
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: you declared `ws` but never gave it a value.

Comment: Fix your code by changing ws.Range -> ActiveSheet.Range